# Firefox: Type not vertically centered in button

Tags: css, firefox, typography

Check out the top right search button on http://hyperiontx.cbstage.com/

It's centered correctly in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VFMGR/

It seems that firefox is ignoring my `line-height: 0` declaration on the site. It also seems that it's because of my font-face type - Times New Roman is centered correctly. Why is it doing it and what's the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `padding:0 6px;`. Buttons works like they have `box-sizing:border-box` and there is no need to set top/bottom padding if you have set height for it.

Comment: Wow thanks! Didn't know this about buttons being border-box - it makes complete sense now.